what is the problem with bevel?
when I add bevel this thing appears, normal is good no double vertices

Hello and welcome. Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Maybe internal edges that shouldn't be there ?

Try a M > Merge by Distance or please share your file?

@moonboots I've already done it.

so share your file (only this object)?

@moonboots How do I do this?

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

@moonboots , its not original file, but with the same problem

Use the Geometry > Miter Outer > Arc option of the Bevel modifier (instead of Sharp):

It will prevent the Subdivision Surface modifier to round the faces on the side:

